# How can I use LinerGradient() by variable in Flutter?

Tags: gradient, flutter-animation

**const LinearGradient Gradient_Color = LinearGradient(colors: [
Top_gradient,
Bottom_gradient
]);**

Comment: I used this variable but its didn't work on bgcolor; color; properety in flutter

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.